# Boostrap 3: how to force the content of layout columns to be of same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Situation: I've a row, with 3 columns. I'm using the Bootrstrap native grid system. In each column there is a panel, with some text in the body.

I want that each panel be of the same eight, even if the text doesn't fill the panel body.

How can I do this?

Referring to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wvdye/1/

This is the code

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is what I got actually, but this is the wrong results, extetically not so good. I want every panel to be at 100% of row height, but I'm not able, using CSS to foce it at 100% of the row height (where the row height is automatically the height of the tallest panel).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Using flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wvdye/4/

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .flex {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;

        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Using CSS table https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wvdye/7/

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .table {
        display: table;
    }

    .item {
        display: table-cell;
        float: none;
        height: 100%;
    }    

    .panel {
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really there is no a native way with CSS 2? A lot of my users still uses old browsers (sigh...)

Comment: I updated answer so take a look. This is support for css table http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html, http://caniuse.com/#search=table. And except these two or using JS i dont think there is other good solution for this, but i might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

jQuery:

```
var $maxH = 0;
$('.panel').each(function() {
    if( $(this).outerHeight() > $maxH ) {
        $maxH = $(this).outerHeight();
    }
});

$('.panel').outerHeight($maxH);
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wvdye/6/

This will get the height of the heightest panel and will set it to the others

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the .panel-body class a min-height.

```
.panel-body { min-height: 300px; }
```

When the screen size changes, you can use media queries to give the panel-body's min-height a different value.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .panel-body { min-height: 100px; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Step 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
                <p>
                    dsadj akshdajksh dkashdjk ahskdjhaskjh dashdjkasdasdasd 
                    asdasdas lkaskljdasklj ldajskljdlasjdlaj sldaskdlkajklsdasd as
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wvdye/3/

Comment: I don't want to use min-height. it don't want to work with pixels in 2015 !